# SSE doen't work with vue-cli devServer proxy

Tags: webpack-dev-server, vue-cli, server-sent-events

I recently move from vue-cli 4.5.x to 5.0.x.

Since this upgrade it seems **Server Sent Events (SSE) doesn't work any more with the WebPack Dev Server.**
(I'm currently using vue-sse)

Note in production it works perfectly.

My devServer config looks like :

```js
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems possible workarounds are :

1. **Disable compression** in the webpack devserver config.
2. **Send Content-Type: `no-transform`** in the response header.

(source : https://composed.blog/sse-webpack-dev-server)

I didn't test the 2. way but the 1. works for me.

```js
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
    // To disable compression : 
    compress: false
  },
```

If this doesn't help maybe you face this similar issue : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/server-sent-events-are-not-working-with-vue-cli-devserver-proxy-and-node-16-0/125450